# What causes this initializer inheritance issue with UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: objective-c, swift, initializer, designated-initializer

I'm trying to create a simple Swift subclass of UIBarButtonItem:

```
class LabelBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
  let label: UILabel

  init(text: String) {
    self.label = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    self.label.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    super.init(customView: self.label)
    self.label.text = text
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

but when I try to instantiate this:

```
let countButton = LabelBarButtonItem(text: "0 items")
```

the code compiles correctly but fails at runtime with:

```
fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class 'TestProject.LabelBarButtonItem'
```

I can't understand why this happens in this case, or what principle causes this problem in general. The `init(text)` initializer should delegate directly to `init(customView)` in the superclass. Why is `init()` called at all? It shouldn't be involved.

Can anyone explain what's happening? Similar problems have popped up when I've tried to subclass other UIKit classes

Comment: here's an example of subclassing UILabel, which may possibly help http://stackoverflow.com/q/32662344/294884

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that `init(customView:)` calls `init()`.

And since you have a required initializer, you no longer inherit `init()`. Thus, you have to implement it, even if just to call `super.init()`.

You then face the (mild) annoyance of having to initialize all your properties in `init()` as well as in `init(text:)`. However, in your particular case, there was no need to do that in an initializer in the first place. I'd write your class like this:

```
class LabelBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    init(text: String) {
        super.init(customView: self.label)
        self.label.text = text
        self.label.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    }
    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

In your comment, you ask:

> But now if I override init(), clients of my class can create an invalid instance of LabelBarButtonItem by just calling LabelBarButtonItem()

Correct. That's why I have marked the `init()` override as `private`. Note that this works only if this class is off in a file by itself.

Another possibility is to mark all your initializers (including `init(coder:)`) as `convenience`. Now you inherit `init()` and the whole problem goes away. However, this introduces another set of issues and is left as an exercise for the reader.

Just to clarify, I regard this entire situation as a bug in Swift. It didn't behave like this, IIRC, until quite a recent revision (Xcode 6.1?). You are being hemmed in by the fact that `super.init(customView:)` calls *your* `init()`. You could argue that that's wrong; you have a good use case for a bug report. Also the crash at runtime seems like wrong behavior; if this was going to happen, why didn't the compiler stop us? Perhaps someone else can justify what Swift does in this situation. I'm just trying to explain it.

**EDIT** This answer is from 2014 and was intended to work around a bug that existed at that time. In modern iOS versions the bug is gone, and you can either say this:

```
class LabelBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
    init(text: String) {
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.text = text
        label.sizeToFit()
        super.init()
        self.customView = label
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

or you can say this:

```
class LabelBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
    convenience init(text: String) {
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.text = text
        label.sizeToFit()
        self.init(customView: label)
    }
}
```

Neither of those was possible at the moment in time when the question was originally asked.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But now if I override `init()`, clients of my class can create an invalid instance of `LabelBarButtonItem` by just calling `LabelBarButtonItem()` (no default text passed in). Can I override `init()`, delete to the superclass, and somehow make this initializer hidden to outside code?

Comment: @Bill I've expanded my answer considerably, incorporating your question and moving my comments into it. See what you think...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I appreciate it! I just submitted a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @Bill I submitted one too, using a shortened version of your code as an example; it's a great use case.

Comment: Hey @matt, thanks for your great answer.  Does this case still apply in modern Swift (2.2 and above)?  Are there any changes that would help with this `init(coder:)` mess?

Comment: @JAL if you think this is about `init(coder:)` you have not understood the problem or my answer. Nothing about the `init(coder:)` requirement has changed or will change, and it is irrelevant here.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the `private override init()`.

Comment: @JAL Ah. That was a bug in Cocoa, and it was fixed in the next major release. Nothing to do with Swift (except that Swift elicits the bug).

Comment: @matt, perhaps update the code to reflect that it no longer works with Swift 3 and 4?  This works for previous versions of Swift though. I had to use Nahuel Roldan's answer below.

Comment: @user1171911 You are looking at ancient history: 2014! This was what was need to solve a problem then. There is no need for _any_ of the code in my answer because now _there is no problem_. You just make your initializer a convenience initializer and stop. No need for any other code. Do _not_ override `init` or `init(coder:)`.

Comment: @matt ancient history aside, its still a top hitting Google search rank. As such I was making a kind suggestion to update your answer so that A. the post's quality is improved and B. you get more upvotes thus improving your own rank.  Again, just a suggestion. Also, you might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/conduct specifically "tone".  Cheers!

Comment: @user1171911 I modified the answer to point out that it is no longer applicable. But this is not because the code "no longer works with Swift 3 and 4", but because a bug in _iOS_ was fixed. The _entire question and answer_ are no longer needed. That's just the way it is on a site where things stick around.

Answer (score 5):

I had to subclass UIBarButtonItem for a project and following the answer of Matt was more than enough, with one little difference. I had to add convenience to the initializer for the code to work. In my case, I don't have a property in my subclass.

Here's the code working for Swift 3, in case it helps anyone.

```
class PlayerBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {

convenience init(assetName: String, target: Any, selector: Selector) {

    let barButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34))
    let barButtonImage = UIImage(named: assetName)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    barButton.setImage(barButtonImage, for: .normal)
    barButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
    barButton.addTarget(target, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)

    self.init(customView: barButton)
}

private override init() {
    super.init()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Comment: Correct, initWithCustomView is a convenience initializer and thus should be chained with self as you have done.

Comment: There was never any need to override `init` and `init(coder:)`. Just make your initializer a convenience initializer and stop. This is because Apple fixed the bug where `init(customView:)` was a designated initializer. Now it is a convenience initializer as it should have been all along. In 2017 there is no bug to work around.